Returning to medicine after a long break
I graduated from medical school roughly 10 years ago with top grades, but I have only practiced medicine for around 3 years after graduation. What made me leave medicine is that I was very passionate about a different field (physics), and I was able to get admitted to a PhD program studying theoretical physics. However, due to a bad fit with the research group and several other factors, I decided that I am no longer interested in this career trajectory, and would really like to go back to medical practice. Would it be even possible to go back to the medical profession after such a long break? I currently do the PhD at a different country, but I have the option to go back to my country and get one or two years of medical experience before applying to residency. How would an employer view someone who had made such a radical career shift?

Please add the country tag that you want to go back to study medicine.

And why not find another physics research group that you fit better with? There are lots of them out there.

What type of medicine and what type of doctor do you want to be? E.g: pediatrician, anesthesiologist, obgyn etc? Have you done your internship? Is your degree the mbbs?

Random internet people can't really help you.
That being said, is there any place in the world that doesn't need more MDs?
If you are qualified, current on licenses/certifications, and want to, what would be the hindrance?
Good luck and save lives!

Some countries have brutal conditions before someone with overseas qualifications are allowed to practice medicine. I personally know 2 people who were doctors in their own country, one is a medical receptionist and has been trying to jump hoops for years to be allowed, the other gave up and became a nurse.  And we of course have a doctor shortage.

@solarflare  The OP referenced going back to the country of the MD before applying for residency. From that I assume, the country isn't an issue.

Assuming that your united-kingdom tag means you're considering medical practice in the UK: we are desperately short of qualified doctors, and consistently importing them from other countries. Assuming you were in good standing when you left, we'll have you back.
